# Elasticsearch - Kibana for non-log data visualizations

Tags: elasticsearch, visualization, kibana

I am exploring the possibility of using Elasticsearch and Kibana combo to visualize non-log data. What I mean by that is I want to feed some business related data and be able to slice/dice using different visualizations Kibana exposes. Has anyone tried this, is this worth spending time on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's worth spending the time because the time-investment to prove it out is fairly small.

Make sure Kibana supports the visualizations you need.

If you need end-users to use your solution, you may not have the *polish* required (custom styles, pluggable viz, fine-grained access control, and the ability to integrate a dashboard effectively within an application).

But for analysis and internal dashboarding it's super quick to set up!